What is the advantage of using spherical tensor over cartesian tensor?
I am trying to train a machine-learning model to forecast the polarizability of atoms within a molecule. Typically, the tensor is characterised as a Cartesian rank-2 tensor, like this:
$$\alpha= \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{xx}&\alpha_{xy}&\alpha_{xz}\\\alpha_{yx}&\alpha_{yy}&\alpha_{yz}\\\alpha_{zx}&\alpha_{zy}&\alpha_{zz}\end{bmatrix}$$
People often use the irreducible spherical tensor when training ML models. Is there a specific reason for this? Also, what is the simplest method to convert from one representation to the other?

Review WP. Normally people are interested in how angular momentum meshes with tensor objects, and that is best analyzed in the spherical basis, as detailed in QM texts.

The Coulomb potential is spherically symmetric. As a consequence, the wave functions of electrons orbiting a nucleus contain spherical harmonics. Therefore it is better to work in a spherical basis.

I see. Is there an easy way to then convert the rank-2 tensor from the cartesian basis to an irreducible spherical tensor?

The Cartesian tensor is just $3\times 3=9$ values tied to an arbitrary coordinate system, and they get scrambled by rotations.
While as you point out, spherical tensors are irreducible, and that means: under rotations, they don't mix. With them you have $2j+1$ for $j=(0,1,2)$, or $ 1 + 3 + 5 = 9$ values to represent in a coordinate system.
Now what is one dimensional and is unchanged under rotation? That is a scalar, and the scale you can make from a tensor is the trace:
$$ T_0^0 = \frac 1 3 \alpha_{ii} = \frac 1 3(\alpha_{xx}
+ \alpha_{yy}+\alpha_{zz}) $$
Asking the same question for "$3$", that is a vector, and the vector like thing you can make from a tensor goes like this: First, take the 3 antisymmetric components:
$$ A_{ij} = \alpha_{ij} - \alpha_{ji} $$
and then turn it into an (axial) vector:
$$ a_i = \epsilon_{ijk}A_{jk} $$
Now that is still Cartesian vector...in the spherical form, you pick:
$$ T_1^0 = \sqrt{\frac 1 2}(\alpha_{xy}-\alpha_{yx}) $$
$$ T_1^{\pm 1} = \mp\sqrt{\frac 1 2}\Big(
(\alpha_{yz}-\alpha_{zy}) \pm i
(\alpha_{zx}-\alpha_{xz})
\Big)$$
These are complex, but they are eigenvectors of $z$ rotations with eigenvalues $\exp(im\theta)$,
and they are closed under rotations, just like the $Y_{l=1}^m$.
Now the remaining 5 degrees of freedom are make up the natural form rank 2 tensor, which is symmetric:
$$ S_{ij} = \frac 1 2 (\alpha_{ij}+\alpha_{ji} )$$
and trace-free:
$$ N_{ij} = S_{ij} - \frac 1 3 \delta_{ij}{\rm Tr}(S) $$
From there you get:
$$ T_2^0 = \sqrt{\frac 3 2}N_{zz} $$
$$ T_2^{\pm 1} = \frac 1 2 \big(
N_{zx} + iN_{yz} 
\big)$$
$$ T_2^{\pm 2} = \frac 1 2 \big(
N_{xx} -N_{yy}\pm 2 iN_{xy} 
\big)$$
which rotate just like $Y_2^m$, and have the same shape.
For the pure rank-2, the $m=\pm 1$ can probably be diagonalized away, leaving:
$$ T_0^2 $$
which tells you the polarized thing is oblate or prolate, and
$$ T_2^2 + T_2^{-2} $$
which is non-zero if the average equatorial cut is ellipsoidal (and not a circle).
So the spherical form is directly relatable to a shape that you can visualize, and they are easy to rotate, basically one of these:

Regarding normalization and sign conventions...you may find different results elsewhere.

Why are there complex number? I believe in this case I should use the real part

@manuelpb oh, I mentioned that and edited it. So the complex stuff is for atomic orbitals and is required if you want tensors that are eigenstates of rotations. It's really the same as cos/sin vs exp(ix) when doing plane waves. Just look at a table of real spherical harmonics (solid harmonics, maybe?), esp. in cartesian coordinates, and the formula are absolutely similar to the tensor formula I show. But the details: signs, normalization, require some effort to get right.
